# Google Sheets' SUM based on criteria of criteria in multiple sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, criteria, google-sheets-formula

On the same Google sheet document, meant to manage multiple License keys, I've got three different sheets.

- The first sheet is the list of the Keys.
  As soon as a key is used, I set its user.
- The second sheet is the list of the Users.
  As soon as I have a new user, I set its name and its role.
- The third sheet is the list of the Roles.
  This is a list of the different roles that needs a key.

Problem:
On the third sheet, I'd like to count how many keys are used for each role.

Example:
I'm Paul, I'm UX Designer, and I use one key.

On the first sheet, one key is set to my name. On the second sheet, my name is set to the role of UX Designer.

I'm basically the only UX set with one key. So, on the third sheet, it should count 1 as the number of keys used by the role "UX Designer".

Many thanks in advance, I hope I was clear!

Comment: Could you use an additional column in the first sheet to vlookup() the user's role?  Then it would just be a countif() formula off the first sheet.

Comment: are keys in 1st sheet numbers or words?

Answer (score 1):

if the key is a numeric value:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({E2:E, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D, A2:B, 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

if the key is text string:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({E2:E, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D, A2:B, 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image: 0]